# Проверка массива через input с выводом на экран js

Tags: javascript

Мне нужно реализовать такую штуку: В поле input вставляются цифры. После нажатия кнопки или Enter необходимо произвести проверку в массиве. Если в массиве есть сходство, то в другое поле выводится слово "Найден", если сходство не найдено, то "Не найден".

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где почитать или как это реализовать для IE11?

У меня есть код:

```
<input type="text" id="test">

 jQuery('#test').on('input', function(){
   let arr = ['test text', 'qwe', 'abcd'];
   if (jQuery.inArray(this.value,arr) > -1){
     console.log('такой элемент есть');
   } else{
     console.log('нет элемента');
   }
 });
```

Но я не пойму как вывести значение не в консоль, а в какой-нибудь div
Спасибо!

Comment: Я ничего не понял.

Comment: Стоит уточнить, сходство чего с чем нужно проверять. Лучше привести примеры.

Comment: @vsemozhebuty Есть массив, в котором записано, например, 123, 1234,12345. При введении в input 123 должно быть выведено значение "Найден", если ввести 154 - "Не найден"

Comment: Что Вы не знаете как сделать? 1. Получить значение из инпута? 2. Проверить, есть ли значение в массиве? 3. Вывести текст на страницу?

Comment: @Igor У меня есть код: <input type="text" id="test">

jQuery('#test').on('input',function(){
  let arr = ['test text', 'qwe', 'abcd'];
    if (jQuery.inArray(this.value,arr) > -1){console.log('такой элемент есть'); }
    else{  console.log('нет элемента');}
  });
Но я не пойму как вывести значение не в консоль, а в какой-нибудь div

Comment: @Grimm Код - в вопрос.

Comment: @Igor добавил, спасибо

Comment: `$('some div selector').text('такой элемент есть');`

Comment: @Igor не получается:(

Comment: Вы неаккуратно скопировали к себе мой код.

Comment: @Igor Я беру код: $('some div selector').text('такой элемент есть'); и вставляю его вместо console.log('такой элемент есть');

Comment: Что значат слова "some div selector"?

Comment: @Igor если я правильно понимаю, то метод some проверяет есть ли элемент в массиве, но это не точно. Сложно даётся js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы что то выводить куда то, нужно сначала создать для этого элемент, например span. Далее чтобы явно указать куда выводить, обратись к этому элементу как посоветовал @Igor $('some div selector').text('такой элемент есть'), только вместо 'some div selector' укажи span или же обратись по id через #. Учи сначала ванильный JS, а JQuery приложится.

```js
  $('#test').on('input', function(){
    let arr = ['test text', 'qwe', 'abcd'];
    if (arr.indexOf(this.value) > -1){
      $('#result').text('такой элемент есть');
    } else{
      $('#result').text('нет элемента');
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <input type="text" id="test">
  <span id="result"></span>
```

Comment: СПАСИБО БОЛЬШОЕ!!!